# How to hide pagination on json file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have implemented pagination on index page. I want that json file doesn't use paginate and select all results on one page.

**index.html.haml**

```
  def index
    @phrases = Phrase.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
  end
```

**index.json.jbuilder**

```
json.phrases @phrases do |phrase|
  json.expression phrase.expression
  json.meaning strip_tags(phrase.meaning)
end
```

Now I have the result, where the json url looks like: `/phrases.json, /phrases.json?page=2, /phrases.json?page=3 itp`. I want have only `/phrases.json`and all results from pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { @phrases = Phrase.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4) }
    format.json { @phrases = Phrase.all }
  end
end
```

As an aside - I generally set the `page` and `per_page` values as constants on the resource I am paginating to easily change in the future if needed.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It's very simple. Thank you @DavidStump !

Comment: Glad it was straightforward.

Feel free to accept as the answer to help other folks if they stumble across this.